# How does DKIM prevent impersonation?

Tags: dkim, spoofing

I understand that DKIM can be used to prevent the spoofing of the "From:" header in an email.  Email receivers can validate the DKIM-Signature to verify the "From:" header.

```
    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; **d=example.com**; 
h=from:to:subject:content-type; **s=smtpapi**; 
bh=Qdu07jaeIipfZPkXZqzhD3HXzeo=; b=skdennE1MwDXUGfm/mox/OF8MJjaq
jrE3ETrbeE4PdvokFigU5qTuf2LJ8M9MmxCm4ji6G+CG4u7eKeCdMgAFgEwZCVhp
8UFYUwXkHFqgzKznGremWWHaXU9aIzUtWyFuOziZhqcP3Jn7/V8xyaCEIPP0dz6b
aaaI87oazVBMp8=
From: CEO <ceo@example.com>
```

For instance, in this email header, the DKIM-Signature says to check "smtpapi._domainkey.example.com" for the public key used to sign the email headers.

But couldn't the attacker simply replace the entire DKIM-Signature content to point to another domain that they control, and re-generate the DKIM-Signature with a set of keys that they own?  This would create a valid DKIM-Signature, but would allow email spoofing.

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed; **d=attackerDomain.net**; 
h=from:to:subject:content-type; **s=attackerKey**; 
bh=Qdu07jaeIipfZPkXZqzhD3HXzeo=; b=skdennE1MwDXUGfm/mox/OF8MJjaq
jrE3ETrbeE4PdvokFigU5qTuf2LJ8M9MmxCm4ji6G+CG4u7eKeCdMgAFgEwZCVhp
8UFYUwXkHFqgzKznGremWWHaXU9aIzUtWyFuOziZhqcP3Jn7/V8xyaCEIPP0dz6b
aaaI87oazVBMp8=
From: CEO <ceo@example.com>
```

Using DKIM, would an email receiver be able to determine that the first email is valid, while the second email is spoofed?  How does the email receiver know which DKIM servers are authoritative for the "example.com" domain?  (example.com vs attackerDomain.net)

Comment: Not a programming question. Maybe ask in superuser.com?

Answer (score 1):

If they created a new key pair and point it to their domain, then they would be authenticating on said domain and not the domain they are trying to spoof.

In order for them to spoof a legitimate domain, they would need to obtain your private key.  Therefore, signing out on their mail server with the private key.

However, they will not pass SPF authentication because the server they are sending from are not authorized.

When your legitimate mail server sends out mail, it will sign the mail with a crypto signature using your private key.  The receiving e-mail servers does a look up on the public key (remember, its your public key that you publish yourself) and validates it.

Answer (score 0):

### SHORT ANSWER:

DKIM makes impersonation ***DIFFICULT***, not ***IMPOSSIBLE***:

All a DKIM validated email proves is that it came from the domain whose key signed it. It might have come from a legitimate member of the organization, or it might be from a hacker who has gained access to their DKIM configured mail server either as an open-relay or through a compromised user's account that could put mail through the server.

But an email FAILING DKIM validation on the recipient's mail server **DOES** necessarily prove forgery and/or tampering in transit. A subtle but very important nuance.

So the only thing a DKIM signed email can prove in absolute terms is in the case of **FAILED** test: the email is either spoofed and/or has been modified in transit. An email **PASSING** DKIM validation only proves the mail was signed by the domain's key.

And in the case of an unauthorized user- *somebody without a set of credentials issued by the organization to use their mail server*- or an open-relay, then DKIM validation can actually serve to confer credibility on a bad actor leading staff to let their guard down when considering its' content.

### LONGER Answer:

I received a DKIM signed email notifying me:

```
The password for your email account (victim@example.com) expires today 10/11/2022 12:01:50 p.m..

Keep and continue with the same password using the below portal.
```

I opened "view Source" and the link to the button was revealed to be:

```
https://jccm.com.ve/wap/MailUpdateFresh/index.html#victim@example.com
```

I found such a claim incredulous as I configured and administrate my own mail server. I have no relationship with any companies in Venezuela in respect to the provision of my mail services.

This clearly was a phishing email.

### How did the Phishing email pass DKIM Validation?

So I checked the headers and found the email had successfully passed DKIM validation:

```
Received-SPF: pass (ee-smarts.top: 106.75.143.14 is authorized to use 
'sales@ee-smarts.top' in 'mfrom' identity (mechanism 'a' matched)) 
receiver=mail.example.com; identity=mailfrom; envelope-
from="sales@ee-smarts.top"; helo=ee-smarts.top; client-ip=106.75.143.14

Authentication-Results: mail.example.com;
dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=ee-smarts.top 
header.i=sales@ee-smarts.top header.a=rsa-sha1 header.s=default header.b=EO/D+N5H

Received: from ee-smarts.top (ee-smarts.top [106.75.143.14])
(using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
(No client certificate requested)
by mail.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id BD4245DAF4
for <victim@example.com>; Tue, 11 Oct 2022 13:02:44 +0100 (BST)

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=default; d=ee-smarts.top;
```

Using the value of `s=default` in the header I then checked the TXT record for the key:

```
host -t txt default._domainkey.ee-smarts.top

default._domainkey.ee-smarts.top descriptive text "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; 
p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCteqwk5m985UgrkYNFy0U6I6k+
QYGTilepE1Mrit5+LXAMFVfdArvbK99AljxpbSOJEOYvkQmAqgtCBgD0tlSmGjiFCQ
A7ylPzp9Owsq/OCPjpAMWA/eHwZua8FKFwPcPvRpww34z9lNr0+XJOb5+6B16tV+BK
La5y8fUgpCLKGQIDAQAB"
```

As far as I could see, the sending mail server **WAS** configured for DKIM and thus my own mail server rightly passed the validation.

### So What happened?

Only two things were possible:

- Either somebody was foolish enough to DKIM-sign phishing emails from their own domain ***OR***
- The phisihing email was passed through a DKIM-configured **OPEN-RELAY** mail server

[Further investigation](https://sdf.org/?spammers) revealed the later was the case:

```
The following are attempts from publically listed open relays on 
ordb.org, spamhaus.org and spamcop.net. If you're here, don't contact us 
to get off.  We do not determine who is in the ORDB. (These are the 
connect attempts we've denied for the previous day)
```

[image: Listing of the open relay]

### What was the trick?

The miscreants weren't trying to get me to respond to the message itself, but merely trick me into clicking on a link in the email which now had DKIM-conferred credibility to trick me into compromising my email account credentials. Notice they didn't want me to **CHANGE** my credentials: the Phishers' defaults were "**KEEP SAME PASSWORD**"

### Conclusion

In this case, DKIM served to confer a high level of credibility to phishers attempting to gain my email credentials. So DKIM works, but only if the DKIM configured mail server is not an open-relay. Thus, DKIM cannot 100% guarantee that impersonation is not possible in the case of an Open-Relay. This is a serious achilles' heal with DKIM from my own observations.